# Check connection refused error after Selenium Chrome webdriver .get

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, tdd

I run Selenium 3.141 tests with Chrome WebDriver. If I forget to start web server, Chrome gives `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error. But `.get` method doesn't raise any exception as if page was successfully loaded. Is it possible to raise an exception on this error?

```py
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.assertIn('page title', self.browser.title)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified  `get` method to check for some browser related errors:

```
class Chrome(webdriver.Chrome):
    def get(self, url):
        super().get(url)
        self.raise_browser_errors()

    def raise_browser_errors(self):
        """
        Check webpage for browser errors.
        See Firefox driver errors in chapter 9.2
        """
        err_status = ('ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED', 'ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED')
        for err in err_status:
            if err in self.page_source:
                msg = "Reached error page: %s (%s)" % (err, self.current_url)
                raise WebDriverException(msg)
```

Firefox webdriver behaviour can be seen in [TDD book  chapter 9.2](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_manual_deployment.html#_as_always_start_with_a_test).